# Google OAuth throwing edirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: django, google-plus, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to add Google Authentication to my Django project. I have been able to configure my project to work with my app on Heroku using a different Oauth client object but I can't seem to get it to work for my development server.

I keep getting the error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request, http://localhost:8000, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

from Google.

My Authorized Javascript origin is:

```
https://localhost:8000
http://localhost:8000
```

My Authorized Redirect URIs are:

```
https://localhost:8000
https://localhost:8000/
https://localhost
http://localhost:8000
http://localhost:8000/
http://localhost
```

(I tried all of these combos based on comments from similar questions.)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated as I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere in the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Each time I changed the Client in the developer console I neglected to make the corresponding update in the Django template. I was using the wrong client the whole time - careless mistake.